# jQuery: selecting list items

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following list:

```
<ul id="bar">
   <li>
      Doctor Who
      <ul>
         <li>Classic Who</li>
         <li>2005+</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I've been poggling around for coming up 3 hours now and have still not figured out how to select the element 'Classic Who'. I'm truly stuck.

I'm using jQuery BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's the selector [this is live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rnvVP/1/)

```
$('ul#bar ul li:first').text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way

$("#bar li ul li:eq(0)")

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#bar li ul').find('li:first-child').text();
```